# How to call a shortcut inside a VS Code extension by API?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Is it possible to execute a shortcut like `Ctrl L,L` for a `vscode.window.activeTextEditor`?

`Ctrl L,L` selects two lines.

I want to be able to run any shortcut inside an active editor by VSCode API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VsCode shortcuts bind keyboard input to named "commands".
User can rebind their keys to different command.
Try [executeCommand](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#3586) by command name.

Comment: How should I do this for the above example?

Comment: @HamedFathi call `vscode.commands.executeCommand('expandLineSelection');` twice.